# How do i add a lead (email, name) against a list in Marketo via API

Tags: marketo

Marketo API is so confusing for a new user like myself. I have an email and name and would love to pass that to marketo. How do I do that?

Comment: Would you like just to insert a lead, or do you need to assign the new lead to a list or a program as well?

Comment: I would love to learn how to do both @dferenc so I can better understand how Marketo API works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push a lead record to Marketo via the REST API, there are a couple of endpoints you can choose from:

- [Sync Leads](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Leads/syncLeadUsingPOST) at `POST /rest/v1/leads.json`
- [Push Lead](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Leads/pushToMarketoUsingPOST) at `POST /rest/v1/leads/push.json`
- [Import Leads](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Bulk_Leads/importLeadUsingPOST) at `POST /bulk/v1/leads.json`

Out of these three, the Sync Leads might be the easiest to use, as that requires the least amout of additional parameters.
Basically, you have to make a POST request to the
`https://<MUNCHKIN_ID>.mktorest.com/rest/v1/leads.json?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>` url with your data sent in the body of the request.

You will find your `MUNCHKIN_ID` under *Admin > Integration > Munchkin* tab in your instance. While still in the admin area, you should also create an API user (or allow API access for your own user), set up a LaunchPoint service with that user for the REST API and finally request an –temporary, valid for 1 hour– access token to test the connection. The whole process is described in detail under the [Authentication](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/authentication/#creating_an_access_token) chapter of the REST API documentation.

Once you have a –still valid– access token, you can make the call above with your lead information provided in the following data structure:

```
{  
   "action":"createOrUpdate",
   "lookupField":"email",
   "input":[  
        {  
            "email":"collizo@4sky.com",
            "firstName":"Collizo4sky"
        },
        // …more leads (up to 300) if needed
    ]
}
```

In case you use php, here is an example code:

```php
$munchkinId = '123-ABC-456';
$accessToken = 'abcdefgh-1234-5678-abcd-12345678abcd:lon';

$url = "https://{$munchkinId}.mktorest.com/rest/v1/leads.json?access_token={$accessToken}";
$dataJSON = [
    'action'      => 'createOrUpdate',
    'lookupField' => 'email',
    'input'       => [  
        [
            'email'     => 'collizo@4sky.com',
            'firstName' => 'Collizo4sky',
        ],
    ],
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($dataJSON));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);

/**
 * Which should result in a response like this:
 * / 
{
    "requestId":"4033#16612d185ad",
    "result":[
        {
            "id":1042016,
            "status":"created"
        }
    ],
    "success":true
}
/**/
```

Comment: Glad to help! Did this answer your question? If so, please mark it as accepted. Or let me know how to extend it. Thanks!